# suppress additional braces in emacs electric mode

Tags: ruby, emacs

I started using ruby-electric-mode.  I like it except that I am used to closing open brackets myself (the other pairing are still useful to me).  How can I make emacs suppress additional brackets when I type in the closing brackets myself?  I now am manually deleting the auto-magically inserted bracket every time.

Thanks in advance,
Raghu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is for the <kbd>}</kbd> to either jump to the (already inserted) <kbd>}</kbd>, or to simply insert a <kbd>}</kbd> and delete the <kbd>}</kbd> that was inserted earlier by the electric mode.

This code should do what you want, the choice of what to do on <kbd>}</kbd> is toggled by the variable `my-ruby-close-brace-goto-close`.

```
;; assuming
;; (require 'ruby)
;; (require 'ruby-electric)
(defvar my-ruby-close-brace-goto-close t
  "Non-nill indicates to move point to the next }, otherwise insert } 
and delete the following }.")

(defun my-ruby-close-brace ()
  "replacement for ruby-electric-brace for the close brace"
  (interactive)
  (let ((p (point)))
    (if my-ruby-close-brace-goto-close
        (unless (search-forward "}" nil t)
          (message "No close brace found")
          (insert "}"))
      (insert "}")
      (save-excursion (if (search-forward "}" nil t)
                           (delete-char -1))))))
(define-key ruby-mode-map "}" 'my-ruby-close-brace)
```

Comment: Wow! that was awesome. I changed '}' to ')' in your code (for my case) and it started working right-out-of-the-box. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @Raghu FWIW, I used `}` because that's what people generally mean when they say "brace" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket .

Answer (score 2):

It is a “customizable” setting. Run `M-x customize-variable` (<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> if you do not have a Meta key) and customize `ruby-electric-expand-delimiters-list`.

Uncheck “Everything” and check only the ones you want to be automatically inserted. Be sure to also “Save for Future Sessions”.

If you decide that you mostly like the automatic insertions but that there are some places where you want to turn it off for a single keystroke, then use `C-q` (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>) before an open paren/bracket/brace/quote to suppress the automatic insertion of the closing mark.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that does help me. But, is there no way to have the best of both worlds?  I.e., have emacs pair my brackets, but delete the duplicate when I type in the the closing pair myself? This would help me navigate within my code better, since, I can skip-over the emacs inserted characters by typing over them (sort of like the override mode but only for the automatically inserted characters)

Comment: Ahh, it was not clear to me what you wanted to have happen. It looks like Trey's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760859/suppress-additional-braces-in-emacs-electric-mode/1764592#1764592) might work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. The solution I found is to:

- Use [autopair](https://github.com/joaotavora/autopair), which does exactly what you want. Make sure you install it.
- Enable `ruby-electric-mode` but only for `|` because the rest is already taken care of.

This leads to the following code in your `.emacs` file:

```
(use-package autopair
  :config (autopair-global-mode)
  )
(use-package ruby-electric-mode
  :init
  (setq ruby-electric-expand-delimiters-list (quote (124)))
  )
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ruby-electric-mode)
```

This code uses [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package, make sure you installed it (`M-X list-packages`, then find `use-package`, then `i` on the line, then `x` and restart emacs).

Also, that might interest people visiting this thread. I added this code to skip closing delimiters with `TAB`, it helps jumping over them. Comment out the `while` lines (and adjust `)`) to have a single `TAB` jump over all closing delimiters (taken from [emacs board discussion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38445/how-to-hop-the-cursor-over-parenthesis-brackets-single-quotes-and-double-quot)):

```
(use-package bind-key)

(defun special-tab ()
 "Wrapper for tab key invocation. 

  If point is just before a close delimiter, skip forward until 
  there is no closed delimiter in front of point.  Otherwise, invoke
  normal tab command for current mode.

  Must be bound to <tab> using bind-key* macro from bind-key package.

  Note, this function will not be called if `override-global-mode' is
  turned off."
  (interactive)
  (defun next-char-delims (delims)
    (let ((char (and (not (equal (point) (point-max)))
                     (string (char-after (point))))))
      (when char (member char delims))))
  (let ((open '("'" "\"" ")" "]" "}" "|")))
    (if (next-char-delims open)
        (progn (forward-char 1))
               ;;(while (next-char-delims open)
               ;;  (forward-char 1)))
      (call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "TAB"))))))

(if (macrop 'bind-key*)        
    (bind-key* (kbd "<tab>") 'special-tab)
  (user-error "Must have bind-key from use-package.el to use special-tab function"))
```

This time, you need the `bind-key` package for this snippet to work.